# Add options to Dojo Dropdown list box

Tags: javascript, dojo

How to programmatically add an option to a dijit.form.Select . I've looked all over the place and I'm not able to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think looking at the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/form/Select) you would see [addOption](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/form/Select#1_10dijit_form_Select_addOption)

```
mySelect.addOption( { label: "new option", value: 1 } );
```

Comment: I did see that. But when I tried to implement that i was not able to create a dijit.form.__SelectOption. It says its not a constructor...

Comment: mySelect.addOption({ label: "new option", value: 1 });

Comment: that worked. please Append it to the answer. I would like to accept it

Comment: so in the documentation, what did they mean by __SelectOption. Is it just an ordinary object and the properties it should have?

Answer (score 2):

this question is old but I want to add some helpful information:
you can use not only plain text for *label*. Additionally enhanced markup can be used

```
mySelect.addOption( { label: "<div><img src="images/girl.png"> Label </div>", value: 1 } );
```